# php:pass image as a parameter in get url

Tags: php, url

I wish to pass image in `get` url in php. Like how id is passed
For eg. `http://myurl.com?id=1` . Similarly I wish to pass an entire image instead of the id.
How do I do it?

actually i have made a web service in php, and want to test it in browser. The service also contains an image to be passed and saved in database n also on server. So how do i do this?

Comment: Passing image in url is not good approach. You can pass id and get the respective image!

Comment: but i want to save the image, not get it

Comment: Then use `$_POST` method for form fields and for files use `$_FILES`

Comment: He refers to an image already stored on your server. That is a typical scenario: you send only the references of already known objects.

Comment: actually i have made a web service in php, and want to test it in browser. The service also contains an image to be passed and saved in database n also on server. So how do i do this?

Comment: You need explain this in your question! Your title confused here!!

Comment: Have you checked `curl` and `soap` ?

Comment: no i havent, sorry but i am complete noob to this

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to base64 code, and then send the code via GET. There's an easy to use image to base64 code converter at http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Comment: Note however that in reality the maximum length of GET parameters are _not_ unlimited. The size depends on the implementation of http server, proxies and some other components. Also some security enhancements (like for example Suhosin) limit the number and size of those parameters according to their configuration.

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that unlike when sending images via a file upload form post everything sent as a parameter in a get request must be kept in ram memory by the processing http server and the processing chain. This can be a problem with bigger sizes of such parameters and several requests arriving in parallel...

Comment: actually i have made a web service in php, and want to test it in browser. The service also contains an image to be passed and saved in database n also on server. So how do i do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use forms for it?